# What is the best way to use the result of test A as the input of test B in a MEAN-stack application?

Tags: javascript, node.js

What I essentially am trying to build is an application that tests reqs and res's of a web application. I want to allow both for single tests, but also test scenarios where the result of the first test in a series of test is essentially piped to the second, and so on.
What would be the easiest way to do this? I am thinking of encoding the results of the test as a JSON object and passing it along, but I can't help but think there must be a better way to accomplish this. Can anyone suggest an alternative that is less ...messy?

Comment: Show us what you've got

Comment: Sounds easy. Post some code and let us fix it for you! Json is super easy to use but if you're just passing it to another JS function why not just leave the data as is? You don't NEED to encode it at all.

Comment: This is the controller for tests as they are now:http://pastebin.com/9qy3y31n

Answer (score 0):

Try as below:

```
  function F1(options,cb){
     var name = "foo";
     cb(true,name); // incase your operations works fine else use cb(false)
  }


  F1(options,function(cb,name){             //calling function F1
     if(cb){                               //if cb is true
         console.log(name)              //print name or you can use name to any other function
    }
 }
```

Comment: what is cb in this function? Could you please put it in the context of the already written controller? I am relatively new to MEAN stack development and not quite sure how to implement this so it would work the way you describe. Thanks a lot for this already though :)

Comment: cb is callback which return two things first is status either your test A was successful or not and second one is the result which you use in test B

Comment: test B will be wait until test A complete its operations and return a status and value